# Random pick squelize

Tags: javascript, postgresql, ecmascript-6, discord

With Squelize I would like to find a random tag in this model:

```
 const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const Database = require('../PostgreSQL');


let Tag = Database.db.define('tags', {
    userID: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
    userName: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
    guildID: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
    guildName: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
    name: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
    content: { type: Sequelize.STRING(1800) }, // eslint-disable-line new-cap
    type: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false
    },
    example: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false
    },
    exampleID: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        defaultValue: ''
    },
    uses: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        defaultValue: 0
    }
});


module.exports = Tag;
```

And that's my actual code, i'm working with discord.js. So I try to pick into all tags a random tag.

```
    async run(msg) {
        const tag = Tag.findAll({ pickRandomProperty, where: { guildID: msg.guild.id } });
        if (!tag) return null;

        console.log(tag.content)
        return msg.say(tag.content);
    }
};





function pickRandomProperty(obj) {
    var result;
    var count = 0;
    for (var prop in obj)
        if (Math.random() < 1/++count)
           result = prop;
    return result;
}
```

That look like that because that's used w/ discord.js